# Get last update time of a gsheet in R without registering

Tags: r, shiny, google-sheets-api, r-googlesheets

I am working on a shiny app that creates a live report based on the data of a google spreadsheet. I only want to read the whole gsheet again if there are new values in it.

For this, it would be best if I could get the last update time of the gsheet and then decide based on that if I need to read in the data again.

I know that registering the gsheet gives the last update time, but registering takes more time than reading in the whole table if there are only a few values in the table.

[Picture of the result of the microbenchmark comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY8ji.jpg)

Is there a way to get only the time of the last update without registering a gsheet again in R?

Comment: Which version of r-googlesheets are you using?

Comment: I  am using `packageVersion("googlesheets")` ‘0.3.0’

Comment: https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org consider also using the googledrive package to check simple file properties like update time